# managedObjectModel: Error in initWithContentOfURL

Tags: objective-c, core-data, model, init, object-model

Im trying to reuse an xcodeproj which uses data core. I import it into my new project, and when i try to do some classes initializations I got the following error

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter' error when setting de managedObjectModel.

Heres my code:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (managedObjectModel == nil) {

        NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataModel" ofType:@"momd"];
        NSURL    *modelURL  = nil;

        if (modelPath == nil)
            modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataModel" ofType:@"mom"];
        modelURL           = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
        managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    }

    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

The line causing the error is

```
modelURL           = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
```

Looks like that i cant find DataModel. My datamodel file is called DataModel.xcdatamodel

What´s the problem? Am I missing something important?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `nil` into `fileURLWithPath`.

From your code, this means that

```
   modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataModel" ofType:@"mom"];
```

assigns `nil` to `modelPath`, so you might review the correct name for your data model file.

Check also that the data model file is included in your target.

Comment: And how could i check it? I mean, my data model file is called DataModel.xcdatamodel. What else could i do to check whats the actual name?

Comment: Is it added to your current target?

Comment: Rename DataModel.xcdatamodeld file. The problem might solved by closing and reopening the Xcode client.

Answer (score 0):

You File type `mom` should be `momd`.

Then try to print the modelPath or modelURL like below and check for it nil.you passing nil to        `modelURL           = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];`

```
 NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataModel" ofType:@"momd"];
        NSLog(@"%@",modelPath);

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSLog(@"%@",modelURL);
```

Comment: I get (null) as output for both lines.

Comment: Rename DataModel.xcdatamodeld file. The problem might solved by closing and reopening the Xcode client.

Comment: It didnt work. Its like the DataModel.xcdatamodeld is not getting compiled or copied. But its included in the target

Comment: Renaming the model file alone is not enough, because it does not rename the reference to the current model version.

It turns out the model version is stored in a separate plist file. Simply open it in a text editor and change the old name to your new model file name.

File: YourNEWModelFile.xcdatamodeld/.xccurrentversion

<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
     <key>_XCCurrentVersionName</key>
     <string>YourModelFile.xcdatamodel</string>  <-- Change this to YourNEWModelFile
  </dict>
</plist>

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it.

I had to have a copy of my DataModel.xcdatamodel in the same group as my AppDelegate. So I added it from the other xcodeproj and finally it worked